# Descendantadded not firing?

Tags: roblox

im trying to make it so that the enemy moves to the sound value parent's position but descendantadded is not firing, i added a little print thingy on the if statement for soundvalue but it doesnt print.

```
  local debounce = false
  local prevpath = nil

   workspace.DescendantAdded:Connect(function(sound)
   --for i,sound in pairs(workspace:GetDescendants()) do
    if sound.Name == "Soundvalue" and sound:IsA("StringValue") then
         print("Founded")
         local hrp = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Torso")
         local ischasing = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Ischasing")

         if ischasing.Value == false then
             if not debounce then
                debounce = true
                
                 if prevpath ~= nil then
                    prevpath:Destroy()
                 end
                
                if sound.Parent and sound.Parent:IsA("BasePart") then
                    print("aaaaa")
                              local path = game:GetService("PathfindingService"):CreatePath()
                    path:ComputeAsync(hrp.Position, sound.Parent.Position)

                    local waypoints = path:GetWaypoints()

                    prevpath = path

                    for i,waypoint in pairs(waypoints) do
                        if ischasing.Value == false then
                            script.Parent.Enemy:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
                            script.Parent.Enemy.MoveToFinished:Wait()
                        end
                    end
                end
                
                debounce = false
             end                
         end
     end
--end
  end)
```

Comment: where is this Script located?

Comment: inside the npc model

Comment: Try putting `print(sound, sound.ClassName)` as the first line of the DescendantAdded connection. I imagine that the signal is firing but for some reason Soundvalue is either misspelled or it's not a StringValue

Comment: they print out "09:26:23.209  Soundvalue StringValue  -  Server -SoundDetectionScript:5"